# Restricted linear representations of abelian groups

Tags: group-theory, representation-theory

If $G$ is a group (say finite for simplicity though the question applies to infinite groups as well), what can one say about the subgroup $G^*_n = \text{Hom}(G, \mu_n)$ of the group of all linear representations $\text{Hom}(G, \mathbb{C}^\times)$? Note that $n$ is not necessarily the order of the group but can be arbitrary natural number. More specifically, can we compute explicitly $G^*_n$ in general?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $G$ is a finite group then $\text{Hom}(G, \mu_n)\simeq \text{Hom}(G^{ab}, \mu_n)$, where $G^{ab}$ is the abelianization of $G$. So we may assume that $G$ is abelian.

Then writing $G=\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}\oplus\dots\oplus\mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z}$ as a direct sum of cyclic groups, we have
$$ \text{Hom}(G, \mu_n)\simeq\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n_1\mathbb{Z}, \mu_n)\oplus\dots\oplus\text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n_k\mathbb{Z}, \mu_n)$$

Finally, if $\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}$ and $\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z}$ are cyclic groups, then
$$ \text{Hom}(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\mathbb{Z}/m\mathbb{Z})\simeq \mathbb{Z}/d\mathbb{Z}$$
where $d$ is the greatest common divisor of $n$ and $m$. Since $\mu_n$ is a cyclic group, putting all the above results together allows you to determine $\text{Hom}(G, \mu_n)$.